# Laravel 5 misroute?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'll copy the relevant code and then i'll explain the problem.

routes.php

```
get('/movies/create', 'MovieController@create');
```

Moviecontroller.php

```
public function create()
{
    return view('movies.create');
}
```

master.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Edit {{ $movie->name }}</h1>

    {!! Form::model($movie, ['url' => '/movies/' . $movie->id, 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('director') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('description') !!}
        {!! Form::text('rating') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Update movie') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $movie->name }}</h1>
    <h4>Director: {{ $movie->director }}</h4>
    <h4>Rating: {{ $movie->rating }}</h4>
    <p>Description: {{ $movie->description }}</p>
    {!! link_to('/movies/' . $movie->id . '/edit', 'Edit') !!}
@stop
```

so i have this code, but when i go to /movies/create in the browser, it's trying to open show.blade.html, which, of course, will throw an exception  ($movie does not exist). Why does that happen?

Comment: *which, of course, will throw an exception ($movie does not exist). Why does that happen?* Of course... Why does that happen? This is a weird sentence.

Comment: you return view('movies.create'); what is the html for movies.create file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a conflicting route above the one you showed, something like this:

```
get('/movies/{movie}', 'MovieController@show');
get('/movies/create', 'MovieController@create');
```

So when you go to `yoursite.com/movies/create` in your browser, the first route is triggered, and the controller opens `show.blade.php` - but there is no movie for it to show yet.

If you move them the other way around, the create method will work as intended, and you'll still be able to show existing movies:

```
get('/movies/create', 'MovieController@create');
get('/movies/{movie}', 'MovieController@show');
```

Comment: That was it! Never would've thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

best way:

```
php artisan make:controller MovieController
```

and define route

```
Route::resource('movies', 'MovieController');


//available routes
    Verb            Path    
    GET             /movies
    GET             /movies/create   
    POST            /movies
    GET             /movies/{id}          
    GET             /movies/{id}/edit   
    PUT/PATCH       /movies/{id}    
    DELETE          /movies/{id}
```